# The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class App\Entity\SubmitNew

Tags: php, database, forms, symfony

I want to build a simple form that lets users add text to the database but I am getting the following error:

> The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class App\Entity\SubmitNew, but is a(n) string. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms a(n) string to an instance of App\Entity\SubmitNew.

Controller.php

```
    public function index()
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(SubmitNewType::class, SubmitType::class);

        return $this->render('submit_new/index.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

SubmitNewType.php

```
class SubmitNewType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('question')
            ->add('answer')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => SubmitNew::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Hello {% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {{ form(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong since I dont have any syntax error of any sort. Could someone please explain what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Isn't the second argument of `createForm()` supposed to be an instance of the entity? You're passing in the class name there.

Comment: Hey yes, i did edit it know, but i still have the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
    $form = $this->createForm(SubmitNewType::class, SubmitNew::class); //You had SubmitType, when you have to pass the class that you defined in your SubmitNewType

    return $this->render('submit_new/index.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

You were passing SubmitType instead SubmitNew as you are defined in your SubmitNewType

```
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('question')
            ->add('answer')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => SubmitNew::class, //You defined SubmitNew here, so, you have to pass this class in createForm
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey my code now resembles 1:1 how you commented. I sitll get the same error message. My ``$form`` is ``$form = $this->createForm(SubmitNewType::class, SubmitNew::class); and my ``data_class`` is ``'data_class' => SubmitNew::class,``
``

Comment: I set my data as null and it works, but i dont think that is the correct solution.